# Cancelling of asynchronous ReadDirectoryChangesW command

Tags: winapi, asynchronous

An asynchronous call to `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` can be cancelled by the `CancelIo()` function. However, by the time `CancelIo()` has been called, the notification buffer associated with `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` may be half filled in. The question is, what happens with those notifications? Should they be processed in a normal way?

More specifically, I issued an overlapped `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` command with a completion routine, and than cancelled it by means of `CancelIo()`. When my completion routine is called with an `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` error, should I still check the notification buffer for possible notifications?

Clarification:
My File System Listener component successfully serves for my company already more than ten years. Now I'm going to modify the component in order to implement a more sophisticated monitoring policy. With this policy, cancelling a particular `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` request doesn't mean cancelling of monitoring, and I do not want to miss even a single notification.

Comment: Does it really matter? You canceled the monitoring, which means you are not interested in it anymore. I would just ignore the buffer completely and move on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I cancelled a particular request, but not the monitoring, and I do interested in each notification. Please see clarification which I added to the question.

Comment: Again, why does it matter? If you cancel *any* I/O operation, you are telling the system that you don't care about that operation anymore, so you don't need to worry about any buffered data that may have been generated, partially or otherwise, leading up to the cancellation. Why do you care about partial data for something you are cancelling? Can you provide an actual use case example?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I cancel I/O operations for specific file handle, but not _any_  I/O operation in the thread. I do not want to guess whether notifications already reported for one handle will be repeated for the other.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found experimentally that the second parameter of completion routine (dwNumberOfBytesTransfered) in the case of `ReadDirecoryChangesW()` function contains number of bytes written to notification buffer. Unfortunately, I didn't find a clear confirmation of that in documentation.

However, this hypothesis seems reasonable, and if it is always true, I can conclude about presence of notifications by checking of that parameter regardless of the completion routine's first parameter (dwErrorCode). This solves the problem.